# No Docker image for .NET Framework 4.6 SDK

Tags: .net, docker

When I look at the versions of the Docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk on Docker Hub, I only see versions 3.5 and 4.8 are present. Why is it so?

I tried running `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.6` but no luck.

Does this mean I need to upgrade my project to the .NET Framework 4.8 SDK?

Comment: You can always build your own image, but for Microsoft they really shouldn't support old releases but the latest for 4.x (4.8 contains everything of 4.6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean I need to upgrade my project to the .NET Framework 4.8 SDK?

No, the 4.8 SDK is capable of building projects of earlier versions. For that reason, there's really no benefit in publishing SDK Docker images for earlier versions.